# Send image as base64 string through web service

Tags: swift, web-services, base64, photo

I have an app allow user upload a photo from photo library, first the app convert the image to base64 string and then pass the string to server through web service (C#.net).

Finally it is only work on some simple photos (e.g. black & white photos, small photos) but failed if color photos, I am not sure but i guess the base64 string truncated when passing to web server. (May be the string too long). Is it any problem on my code below?

```
func UploadPhoto(img: UIImage){
    let strBase64 = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://xxxxx/uploadimg.asmx/UploadFile")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "Base64String=" + strBase64

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
    {
        data, response, error in

        if error == nil && data!.count > 0, let _ = data {
            do
            {
                print ("API UploadFile Finished")
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print("UploadFile error")
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Might want to use multiform part data?

Comment: What is the error? What is the request timeout?

Comment: Try to send image as Data ```image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)```

Comment: if send image as Data, what data type should be on C# web service? Thanks.

Comment: How to use multiform part data? Thanks.